# How to execute a python script and write output to a file?

Tags: python, linux

i have the following script in python with a while loop

```
from time import sleep
    while True:
        print "hola"
        print "mundo"
        sleep(2)
```

and i want to write the output to a file with the following code:

```
import subprocess
    with open("output.log", "w") as output:
    subprocess.call(["python", "./main.py"], stdout=output);
```

the thing is that the while never ends, the file output.log never gets the output from the script, i wonder if there is a way to do it.

Comment: [`import logging`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/logging.html#simple-examples)

Comment: stdout of python is buffered by default. add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print` or add `-u` option when calling python as subprocess

Comment: sys.stdout.flush() works, but could you gime the example in order to put -u option please ?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do it by the following command.

```
python filename.py > output.log
```

The above command works for both linux and windows.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but there is a simple example, because i have a complex python script and if i can do to handled this command, i can get the output  log that i wanted

Comment: The above command will write anything that is sent to the standard output (print statements) to the file 'output.log'. So if your program printed out "hello world", then running it with the above command would write "hello world" to the log file rather than printing it out.

Comment: In case you have to pass arguments to script, make sure to pass them after the output file name for eg. `python filename.py > output.log --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2`